# Trigger gets fired but Value does not get replaced in a record

Tags: trigger

Can any one help me out.The trigger gets fired but the value is not getting replaced in the record.Is the trigger written correct or any blunt mistakes.Any help very much appreciated.

Im writting a trigger on opportunitylineitem .Based on condition as :

Condition 1:

If Product_Line__c == 'DIE'

a)UnitPrice=0.01

b)Newextension__c=Quantity*0.01

c)PricebookEntry.Product2.Name=Bin_Item_Code__c

Condition 2:

If Product_Line__c != 'DIE'

a)UnitPrice=1

b)Newextension__c=Quantity*1

c)PricebookEntry.Product2.Name=PricebookEntry.Product2.Name(It should be the same product name)

Code:

```
trigger Populate_Extension on OpportunityLineItem(Before Insert, Before Update) {

List < OpportunityLineItem > ListOpportunityLineItem = Trigger.new();

ListOpportunityLineItem = [Select id, PricebookEntry.Product2.Name, PricebookEntry.Product2.Product_Line__c,UnitPrice, Newextension__c, Quantity, Bin_Item_Code__c from OpportunityLineItem ]; 

system.debug('++++++ ' + ListOpportunityLineItem);

for (OpportunityLineItem ol: ListOpportunityLineItem) {

 if (ol.PricebookEntry.Product2.Product_Line__c == 'DIE'){

system.debug('PricebookEntry.Product2.ProductLine!!!!!!!!!' + ol.PricebookEntry.Product2.Product_Line__c);

             ol.UnitPrice = 0.01;
             system.debug('Unitprice%%%%%%%%%%%%' + ol.UnitPrice);

             ol.Newextension__c = ol.Quantity * ol.UnitPrice;
             system.debug('Newextension@@@@@@@@@@@' + ol.Newextension__c);

             ol.PricebookEntry.Product2.Name = ol.Bin_Item_Code__c;
             system.debug('PricebookEntry.Product2.Name#########' + ol.PricebookEntry.Product2.Name);
    }
           else  if (ol.PricebookEntry.Product2.Product_Line__c != 'DIE'){
                 system.debug('PricebookEntry.Product2.ProductLine*******' + ol.PricebookEntry.Product2.Product_Line__c);

             ol.UnitPrice = 1;
             system.debug('Unitprice^^^^^^^^^^^^^^' + ol.UnitPrice);

             ol.Newextension__c = ol.Quantity * ol.UnitPrice;
             system.debug('Newextension$$$$$$$$$$$' + ol.Newextension__c);

             //ol.PricebookEntry.Product2.Name=ol.PricebookEntry.Product.Name;
    }

         }
     }
```

Comment: Don't you need to do a DML update when you finish setting the value ?

Comment: @ Mihai Neagoe:I have done the insertion and updation  but the system throws an Error as :Apex trigger Populate_Extension caused an unexpected exception, contact your administrator: Populate_Extension: execution of BeforeInsert caused by: System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0 with id 00kJ0000008DmtFIAS; first error: INVALID_FIELD_FOR_INSERT_UPDATE, cannot specify Id in an insert call: [Id]: Trigger.Populate_Extension: line 49, column 1  .

Comment: It's an update call not an insert, the error message is clear: cannot specify id in an insert call.

Comment: @Mihai Neagoe:For update : it throws an Error as :execution of BeforeUpdate caused by: System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id 00kJ0000008DmtFIAS; first error: SELF_REFERENCE_FROM_TRIGGER, Object (id = 00kJ0000008DmtF) is currently in trigger Populate_Extension, therefore it cannot recursively update itself: []

Comment: I'm not sure what your updated code is but from what I see from the original post you need to update an OpportunityLineItem. You should search on google how to do updates in Apex

Comment: Why are you doing all those queries for OLI when the trigger context IS the OLI???? Your issue is you are doing a query for the same records that are in the trigger. Simply modify the values of the trigger records, no DML required

Comment: @Eric:I have written the trigger as updated above now.But the o/p in debug show that the trigger is getting executed for the product line !=DIE,but while creating a record the product is selected of product line=DIE and it should fire on the logic written.IS that im making any blunt mistake .Any help very much appreciated.

Comment: Neither of your `IF` statements inside your `For` loop are wrapped in brackets nickey. Instead, they're both completed by `system.debug` statements.  If you'd properly indent your code, it would be MUCH easier to read and those things would more obvious and easier to catch.

Comment: @crmprogdev:I have the bracks correctly in the sandbox .But in the debug logs it shows the previous products added details  ,not the current record details.How to know the current product details in the debug log.Any help very much appreciated.

Comment: @nikkey - you are still doing a query for the oli records which are in the trigger. Updating them WILL NOT update the records. You will not be able to keep querying the entire OLI object as you are doing in your code as there will be too many records. Not really sure what you are trying to do here. If you are limiting your query to the OLI in the trigger then DO NOT do the query, work off of the trigger records.

Comment: @nikkey - I see why you are doing the query, to get the Product2 info, would be much easier to create a formula field to pull that into the OLI record and remove the need to do the query.

Comment: @Eric:We have a formula field created, as extension and that is referenced to the Roll up summary fields in  opportunity object as a field to aggregate .These fields are called out in a controller which is not working as per the requirement.

Comment: @Eric :So Client has asked to create a new field as new extension and write a trigger,and  refrence to the roll up summary field.This trigger is written on condition.I have updated the condition in the query.Plz help me out if my trigger is wrong .Any help very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This will set the unit price for condition a and b in your reqs.

```
Set<Id> pbeIds = new Set<Id>();
for (OpportunityLineItem oli : Trigger.new()) {
    pbeIds.add(oli.PricebookEntryId);
}

Map<Id, PricebookEntry> pbeMap = new Map<Id, PricebookEntry>([select Id, Product2.Product_Line__c from PricebookEntry where Id in :pbeIds]);

for (OpportunityLineItem oli : Trigger.new()) {
    if (pbeMap.get(oli.PricebookEntryId).Product2.Product_Line__c == 'DIE') {
        oli.UnitPrice = 0.01;
        oli.Newextension__c = oli.Quantity * 0.01; 
    } else {
        oli.UnitPrice = 1;
        oli.Newextension__c = oli.Quantity * 1;
    }
}
```

To be honest though item a does not really make any sense. I do not think setting the UnitPrice is really what you want to do, but you know the requirements better than I do. If it is really the case that you do not want to reset the UnitPrice then you can do all of this with formulas. Item c does not make any sense because it looks like you want to rename the product for some reason? You may just want an override display name or something?

Comment: :Thanks for your help and reply.The code is working .I would like to add the c)PricebookEntry.Product2.Name=Bin_Item_Code__c  &&  c)PricebookEntry.Product2.Name=PricebookEntry.Product2.Name(It should be the same product name) for both the condition .How to reference this product code.I shall appreciate your help.

Comment: I just said, this is impossible. Please explain what you want to do.

Comment: PricebookEntry.Product2.Name references the name of the product, this is like trying to rename product itself.

Comment: When the product line = DIE , the product name  should be equal to Bin item code (Bin item code has different notation)and when product line !=DIE the product name should be the same.This all is used to generate invoice in a visual force page by referencing these fields.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but does not work that way. PricebookEntry.Product2.Name is a reference to the name of the product, it cant be changed on a per opportunity line item basis. You should probably create another field on your opportunity line (Display name or something) and populate that instead. Then on your VF page, reference that field instead of the product name.

Comment: ;I have created a field as PopulateProductName .So Based on condition When the product line = DIE , PopulateProductName =Bin item code ,When the product line! = DIE , PopulateProductName = PricebookEntry.Product2.Name  .When I referenced the new field  PopulateProductName on VF page, in the o/p ,it displays only for the new record the Bin code ,but for the rest of the records it doesn't displays bin code, even if the record has.

Answer (score 0):

Line1: List < OpportunityLineItem > ListOpportunityLineItem = Trigger.new();

Line2: ListOpportunityLineItem = [Select id, PricebookEntry.Product2.Name, PricebookEntry.Product2.Product_Line__c,UnitPrice, Newextension__c, Quantity, Bin_Item_Code__c from OpportunityLineItem ];

In Line 1, ListOpportunityLineItem list holds the records which are being updated.
in Line 2, ListOpportunityLineItem list holds multiple records (irrespective of its updated or not.)

If you want to update fields of record which is currently being updated, then you don't need to query on opportunity line items. Remove that line.(Line2)